# Psycopg2 + Python 2 Unicode decode error with cursor.mogrify

Tags: python-2.7, unicode, encoding, utf-8, psycopg2

I have a database, called `test` with only one column, being a `character varying` column of the name `some_data`. The database has the encoding UTF8 with collation de_DE.utf8.
The connection to this databases is established after the unicode type is registered like:

```
psycopg2.extensions.register_type(psycopg2.extensions.UNICODE)
psycopg2.extensions.register_type(psycopg2.extensions.UNICODEARRAY)
```

and I establish the connection

```
C_test = psycopg.connect(myhost [...])
```

and open a cursor on the connections

```
cur_test = C_test.cursor()
```

I insert my data as unicode strings in `test`, so when I do:

```
cur_prod.execute("INSERT INTO test some_data VALUES ("+u'ö'+");")
```

the table is expected to hold the unicode u'ö' as a 'UTF8' string `"\xc3\xb6"`.

When I select that inserted value, the UNICODE extension guarantees to get me unicode back, and indeed when I select and print the value, I get `'\xf6'`, the unicode for `'ö'`. If I use mogrify on the cursor, like:

```
cur_test.mogrify(u'%s',(u'ö',))
```

I get a string like `"'\xc3\xb6'"`, which I cannot insert due to a UnicodeDecode error. Long story short: Can I use mogrify together with the unicode extension registered, or should I do my string concatenation without mogrify?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, if you register the unicode adapter mogrify will use it.

Comment: In my case it doesn't. Do you have any idea why?